# memory leakage in TensorFlow 2.2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I use TensorFlow 2.2 and I am trying to find best hyper-parameters for my model/dataset. So, I use model.fit inside a for loop where I change learning rate. However, I have memory leakage. Here is my code:

```
for i in range(1,500):
    LR=10**uniform(-5,-3)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=1e-07,amsgrad=False,name="Adam"), metrics=['mse'])
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),verbose=2,batch_size=32, epochs=30)
```

How can I solve memory leakage problem?

Comment: Did this solve your memory leak issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your `compile` and `fit` are inside loop, It would help to create new TF graph and session at every iteration. Consider clearing clutter from model and layers from previous iteration. This can be done using `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()`.

```
for i in range(1,500):
    LR=10**uniform(-5,-3)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LR,beta_1=0.9,beta_2=0.999,epsilon=1e-07,amsgrad=False,name="Adam"), metrics=['mse'])
    model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_data=(x_test,y_test),verbose=2,batch_size=32, epochs=30)
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

Alternatively, you can use `model.train_on_batch` inside the loop.